# bash won't exit on error if a program's output is redirected to log file

Tags: ubuntu, logs, pipe, stderr

```
#!/bin/bash
exec 200>/var/lock/scraper || exit 1
flock -n 200 || exit 1
    cd /home/ubuntu/web_scraper
    /home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v13.12.0/bin/node mongo/scraper.js > logs/scraper.log
flock -u 200
```

basically:

```
node scraper.js > scraper.log
```

doesn't doesn't release the terminal/cmd after an error: so it both fails and never unlocks.
how do I stream to a log file **AND** still exit when a program fails?

Answer (score 0):

the problem was node. node does not exit the script when you throw an error.